# SQL Count when criteria is met

Tags: sql, excel, amazon-web-services

Apologies if this seems like a stupid question but I am new enough to SQL, I am running ODBC and using power query in Excel. I am looking to have for example the following as columns (this is pulled from AWS CTR).
Queue
Call Arrival date 
Calls offered
Calls Answered
Calls Answered (in specified time)

I am finding it difficult to pull the calls answered as a column, below is the current statement I am running and getting errors, If I remove the "calls Answered" statement the query will work as expected.
Any suggestions for this will be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT queue.name as "queue", cast(substring(connectedtosystemtimestamp,1,10) as date) as "call arrival date", count(contactid) as "Calls Offered", count(case when(cast(queue.duration as integer)<30) then 1 end) as "answered below 30 sec", SUM(CASE initiationmethod=’INBOUND’, name IS NOT NULL AND agent IS NOT NULL) AS "Calls answered"
FROM Catalog.db.table
WHERE initiationmethod = 'INBOUND' AND queue is not null
GROUP BY queue.name, cast(substring(connectedtosystemtimestamp,1,10) as date)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not valid SQL:

```
SUM(CASE initiationmethod=’INBOUND’, name IS NOT NULL AND agent IS NOT NULL) AS "Calls answered"
```

Presumably, you want:

```
SUM(CASE 
    WHEN initiationmethod = 'INBOUND' 
        AND name IS NOT NULL 
        AND agent IS NOT NULL 
    THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
END) AS "Calls answered"
```